# How to solve low memory problem in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ram, disk-usage, partitioning

i installed ubuntu12.04 amd64 version inside windows using wubi in a partition of 8GB, and in GParted it shows that 5.12GB used and 3.10 GB unused, The problem is it always shows a message box of low memory , empty trash while downloading something or updating or installing.... how can i solve it????

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the Wubi install, it's probably running low on space. I think it's like a big file on a windows drive, that's used as your Ubuntu partition.

Wubi is no longer a recommended method, and it doesn't work with Windows 8 at all.

To fix it, you could resize the wubi "install", but it's probably a better solution to migrate wubi to a regular install by following this Ubuntu guide here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

And even more Wubi info here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide Especially check out:

- [How do I migrate to a real partition, and/or get rid of Windows entirely?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_migrate_to_a_real_partition.2C_and.2BAC8-or_get_rid_of_Windows_entirely.3F)
- [How do I resize the virtual disks?](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide#How_do_I_resize_the_virtual_disks.3F)

Comment: thanxs dudee, it's worthy......

Comment: You're welcome, feel free to check-mark / select / upvote the answer if you like it, thanks